# How to get component (div) rendering time in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, rendering, performance-testing

How to calculate the rendering time of each component (Divs) and show it to the users in a graph. Eg: Calculating the time taken for UI-Grid to load and render JSON, etc.

I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-performance , it calculates loaded time, but before the DOM renders the items.

How to calculate the component(div) rendering time in AngularJS?

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found a way to calculate the rendering time of each component (Divs)

HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller="Controller1">
    <div custom-performance="log1" content="Content1">{{log1}}</div>
</div>
 <div ng-controller="Controller2">
    <div custom-performance="log2" content="Content2">{{log2}}</div>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Controller1', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'JSON/catlog.json'
  }).success(function(response) {
    $scope.log1 = response;
  }).error(function(error) {

  });
}]);

app.controller('Controller2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.log2 = "Hello World";
}]);

app.directive('customPerformance', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $rootScope.graphOutput = [];
      var start = new Date();
      var endTime = null;
      scope.$watch(attrs.customPerformance, function(newval) {
        if (newval != undefined) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            endTime = (new Date() - start);
            $rootScope.graphOutput.push({
              'content': attrs.content,
              'timeTaken': endTime
            });
            console.log(JSON.stringify($rootScope.graphOutput));
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```